# Python stacked linked list

Tags: python

everything seems to be working with the code below, however i keep getting this error :

> Attribute 'next' defined outside **init**
>   (attribute-defined-outside-init)` at temp.next = self.head (in the
>   push function)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next_node = None

class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def push(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.next = self.head
        self.head = temp

    def pop(self):
        if self.head is None:
            raise IndexError("Can't pop from empty stack.")
        else:
            current = self.head
            self.head = current.next
            return current.data

    def peek(self):
        if self.head is None:
            raise IndexError("Can't peek at empty stack.")
        else:
            return self.head.data
```

Comment: you may want to replace `self.next_node = None` by `self.next = None`

Comment: Yes, that's right, it *is* defined outside `__init__`...

Comment: You define it in `__init__` the same way you have defined other attributes in `__init__`.

Comment: @laa Well, you either have to change the doctest to use `next` or change your code to use `next_node` instead of `next`.

Comment: `self.next_node = None` -> `self.next = None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init function is incorrect.

Instead of

```
def __init__(self, initdata):
    self.data = initdata
    self.next_node = None
```

it should be

```
def __init__(self, initdata):
    self.data = initdata
    self.next= None
```